# Angular UI Drop down scope variable updated from directive does not update the scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have written a directive that updates a scope variable based on the key pressed. The code works fine for me but the variable does not get updated till focus is put back on the dropdown or pulled off. Below is the html and the directive code:

```
<button type="button" drop-select ="card.purchaseType">{{card.purchaseType}}</button>

 appModule.directive('dropSelect', function() {
   return {
     scope: {
       purchaseType:'=dropSelect'
     },
     link: function(scope, element, attrs){
       var items =["Retail Purchases","Prescription Purchases", "Retail and Prescription Purchases"];
        element.on('keyup', function(e){
          // Get the character pressed
          var stringChar = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode), currentItem = scope.purchaseType;
          for(var itemCount = 0; itemCount < items.length; itemCount++){
            if(stringChar == items[itemCount].charAt(0) &&
              currentItem != items[itemCount]){
              scope.purchaseType = items[itemCount];
            }
          }
        });
     }
   }
 })
```

Comment: Reproduce your issue please, use plunker for a demo.

Comment: The cod is somewhat like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/0fXNf1F7iRGGo2wksRQz?p=preview

Comment: I am not sure why its not updating the scope but if it updates the value inside the button does not change even when the directive updates the same.

Answer (score -1):

Try element.on('keypress') instead of a keyup

Comment: May I know the reason for marking it not useful? Isn't that related to the problem?